# Can I obtain trusted SSL certificates without giving out personal information?

Tags: security-certificate

I am launching a site that will require secure (ssl) account login, no payments or credit cards involved. Self signed certificates gives annoying warnings in browsers, so I want to get a trusted SSL certificate from an authority. But I want to keep my personal information anonymous. Is there a major authority out there who doesn't ask for personal information, only requires some sort of proof of domain control?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to pay for an SSL certificate which is trusted by the major OSes/Browsers, so even if the SSL provider didn't ask for your name in the certificate they're going to ask for your name, address and credit card number for payment.

I'd be highly surprised if you found a reputable SSL issuer which doesn't ask for your information, it's kind of the whole point - they need to determine that you own the domain and have rights to request the certificate (which, at the lowest level of checks would involve emailing the domain owner from the WHOIS information, and of course, having a domain means someone has your information already anyway).

Having said that the cheaper SSL providers don't embed ownership information in the certificate anyway, so it's not like your name is going to leak via the cert itself.